# Лишний отступ возле img

Tags: html, css

Как убрать это лишний отступ в само низу , под изображением ?
Читал статью на хабре:

> Наверное, многие, при html-верстке, встречали «баг», когда, размещая > в блоке подряд два изображения, между ними возникает промежуток, > примерно в 3-5 пикселей. Этот эффект присутствует не только в горячо > > любимом IE6, но и в других браузерах. Большинство решали это с бубнами – подменой Doctype, убиранием лишних отступов в html-файле и так далее.
>
> Начав искать решение проблемы в интернете, в том числе и на хабре, я понял, что вопросов по этому поводу много, но правильного ответа большинство так и не нашли. В итоге выяснилось, что это вовсе не баг. IMG – внутристрочный элемент, и поэтому к нему применяется свойство vertical-align. В браузерах это свойство задается по умолчанию (в большинстве baseline, если не ошибаюсь).
>
> Достаточно к изображению применить vertical-align:bottom и отступа внизу не будет. В других случаях будет неоднозначность, и браузеры будут вести себя на свое усмотрение.
> https://habrahabr.ru/post/51140/

НО эта методика и все остальные не работают , если способы кроме отрицательного `margin` убрать это отступ ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clear,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  margin: auto;
}
div p {
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear">
  <img src="http://i1.mywishis.in/s/i/wishes/23/11/3/230x0_2311332646a15ea26e2b7172af891d87___jpg____4_1af7f70b.jpg" alt="img">
  <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
</div>
```

для тренировок : http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/WxBQaK?editors=110

Comment: Кажется Вы читали не ту статью. В статье говорится о картинках, вставленных как элемент текста. В Вашем же случае к картинке применен `float`, что делает ее блоком "вне" текста. А решать нужно играя с размером картинки или высотой строки текста (`line-height`)

Comment: проверьте прежде чем делать скорополительные умозаключения

Comment: На самом деле отступа нет, просто высота картинки не кратна высоте строки. Если установить жестко высоту - вполне можно убрать промежуток

Answer (score 1):

Это не из-за картинки отступ, а из-за переноса текста. Можно решить изменением `font-size` или `line-height`

Пример с изменением `line-height`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clear,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  margin: auto;
}
div p {
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 1;
}
img {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear">
  <img src="http://i1.mywishis.in/s/i/wishes/23/11/3/230x0_2311332646a15ea26e2b7172af891d87___jpg____4_1af7f70b.jpg" alt="img">
  <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
</div>
```

Пример с изменением `font-size`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clear,
.clear:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
div {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  margin: auto;
}
div p {
  width: 98%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}
img {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div class="clear">
  <img src="http://i1.mywishis.in/s/i/wishes/23/11/3/230x0_2311332646a15ea26e2b7172af891d87___jpg____4_1af7f70b.jpg" alt="img">
  <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: в обоих ваших примерах внизу изображения есть отступ

Comment: Сайт немного по разному отображает текст, если нажать править>редактировать код и запустить, то форматирование будет немного другое (получше).

Comment: я о том и говорю , что решение должно быть универсальное - я на codepen не зря дал ссылку

Comment: Универсального решения скорее всего нет или он на js, потому что даже на вашем кодепене, если изменять ширину окна, то можно поймать как нормальный отступ, так и большой. Это все из-за строки которая занимает всю ширину, хоть текст и не занимает всю ширину. Можно картинке задать правый отступ, чтоб при появлении отступа нормально смотрелось.

Comment: я задавал же и правый и левый и общий отступ , и собственно потому и возник этот вопрос

Comment: В примере кода только общий `margin: auto;` у `div` и `div p`. Задайте `img` `margin-right: 10px` и в большинстве случаев будет приемлемо, либо задавайте правый отступ по своим брейкпоинтам.

Comment: в принципе , подходит - но решение топорное , хотя работает

Comment: и общий margin:auto; ни на что не влияет: вроде бы , я убрал его , и так же убрал margin-right для img та же фигня

Answer (score 1):

Используйте старый добрый `display:block`.

***Пример №1:***

```css
img {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://gubkabob.xaaa.ru/img/gubka-bob-risuem-24.jpg" alt="">    
</div>
```

***Пример №2 (с текстом):***

```css
img {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <img src="http://gubkabob.xaaa.ru/img/gubka-bob-risuem-24.jpg" alt="">  
  <img src="http://gubkabob.xaaa.ru/img/gubka-bob-risuem-24.jpg" alt="">  
  <p>dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas</p>
</div>

<div class="test">
  <img src="http://gubkabob.xaaa.ru/img/gubka-bob-risuem-24.jpg" alt=""> 
  <p>dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas dsadasdasdas as das das das dasd asd asd asd as dasd asdas</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: а с текстом тот же эксперемент?

Comment: @Geyan пример приведите конкретный, а то так не совсем понятно

Comment: @Geyan добавил пример с текстом, если, конечно, правильно понял

Comment: Nikita мне конечно нравится спанч боб но надо одну картинку и что бы обтекал её текст без нижнего отступа

Comment: @Geyan Пример №2 смотрел? Если есть вопросы пиши в ЛС, #soreadytohelp